# What does "///<exclude/>" mean?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

I have inherited a bunch of C# code.  For a couple of method definitions I find `///<exclude/>` as the only XMLDoc in front of it.  I tried to Google the meaning of that but was not successful. Can someone please explain what that might mean?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In [NDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/) at least, it means that the XML documentation for this member should be excluded. From the [documentation](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/content/tag_exclude.htm):

> The `<exclude/>` tag directs NDoc to exclude the current item from documentation.

It's not clear to me whether this was originally NDoc-specific, but it does also appear to be supported by Sandcastle (in that it's in the [Sandcastle XML comments guide](http://www.ewoodruff.us/xmlcommentsguide/)).

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: To answer THAT question: It' Jon Skeet (period)! ;-)

Comment: I have no evidence that this project uses NDoc.  Maybe someone in the very past tried to start using NDoc.  If there is no other known usage of this thing, I take Jon's answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

From the [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) [documentation](http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/Index.aspx?topic=html/c18d6cb6-e4e4-4944-84ee-f867aa6cfb0d.htm):

> A namespace is excluded via the Namespace Summaries property or an
>   item is excluded because its XML comments include an **<exclude />**
>   tag. This information is merged automatically with the API filter
>   settings. To alter these items, you will need to use the Namespace
>   Summaries property or remove the tag from the item's XML comments.

An official reply:

[A way to exclude documentation?](http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/403591)

And more info about the behavior:

[Problems with missing members and  tag](http://shfb.codeplex.com/discussions/10780)